# How does the claymore work?

Tags: ghost-recon-future-soldier

I've been trying the claymore out in Guerrilla mode, but I'm not sure how it works. It blows up, but I'm not sure when. When I lay it, it shows a cone of vision or something, but I'm not sure what that does. I also haven't seen them blow up a vehicle. What determines when they blow up? Do vehicles activate them too?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the vehicles, but these are anti-personal directional mines. The red cone indicates it's proximity sensor, and if someone gets caught in the direction of the cone the mine blows up inflicting small radius damage.

Anti-Directional mines are useful against most of the enemies, except Bodarks, since they're tougher. Two claymores are required to kill a Bodark, unless he stands too close to it or have taken damage before. I don't think it would have much effect on vehicles. LMGs and grenades + grenade launchers work best against vehicles, especially the LMG, since they penetrate one level of wall and has enough power to damage the vehicle properly

Comment: Hi Hitman, welcome to the site! I've been going over some of your posts and it's good to see you've been bumping up some old questions with new information. We always appreciate users answering old questions which haven't received any answers yet. However, although the content of your answers is good, the grammar of them makes it hard to read, since you don't make use of periods and just seem to clump everything together into one big sentence. I've gone through and touched up most of your existing posts, but if you be more careful about the formatting and grammar in your future posts...

Comment: ...you'll probably get more upvotes and a better response to your answers. Because the content in your answers is good, you just need to present it a little better. Thanks!

Comment: @Wipqozn thanx , sorry for the grammer thing , i don't use english much . so despite my good vocabulary and grammer , i fail to present articles easy to read.